# How to stop the EDMX generator from changing columns names

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

If a table has column names that are the same as the table name the EDMX Generator suffixes the column name with a "1". Ex: Changing Test to Test1 in the sample below.

SQL Server Table definition:

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [Test] nchar NOT NULL,
    [ColumnsTwo] nchar NULL,

EF Model created:

```
     <EntitySetMapping Name="Test">
        <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="AdventureWorksModel.Test">
          <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Test">
            <ScalarProperty Name="ColumnsTwo" ColumnName="ColumnsTwo" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="Test1" ColumnName="Test" />
          </MappingFragment>
        </EntityTypeMapping>
      </EntitySetMapping>
    </EntityContainerMapping>
```

This causes  SqlQueries to throw the error "The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'AdventureWorksModel.Test'. A member of the type, 'Test1', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name."

Why does the DbContext generator modify the column name? The ObjectContext generator left them alone.

How can we fix this? We have no control over the DB schema.

Comment: This should have nothing to do with DbContext generator. It is inside EDMX generator. I guess the former behavior was in VS2010 and the new behavior is in VS2012, isn't it?

Comment: Could be. I will check at my office. Why does it do this? How can I fix this once and for all?

Comment: I happens with VS 2010 too. Maybe the EDMX generator has always changed the column names when columns name = table name. Does anybody know a workaround?

Comment: Replaced DbContext generator by EDMX generator in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot change this behavior. The EDMX generator changes column names, because the C# compiler will not let you have a class with a member of the same name. See [MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/61f03e28-7663-4f5a-b661-0af1bc793591)